# Vista - give me a sign when all start up processes are done

Tags: windows-vista, boot

OK. I am a frustrated VISTA user (like so many others).

I am wondering if there is a way to have some sort of program/function show me when EVERYTHING is loaded after reboot/log-on.

I am asking this because I need to make some changes and I need some sort of cue to tell me when VISTA is done - completely! This way I can see if any changes I make in my settings do anything useful. I plan to sit with a stop-watch and take notes :-)

And I was thinking that perhaps a small script in the start-up folder would do; print something on screen as the last item. Trouble is that I have no idea of how to make this script - or how to make sure it runs as the very last thing.

Comment: try Google "boot measure software" - one of them may do what you want

Comment: Vista has tools built in that log startup times....http://www.zdnet.com/blog/bott/microsofts-hidden-diagnostic-tool-unlocks-vista-startup-secrets/246

Comment: I don't think Vista is ever done starting up.  Best you can hope for is that it lets you use the computer for more than ten seconds without putting up its "swirly".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm replying too early, but monitoring and taking note of every single process starting and finishing isn't possible. The reason for this being many start up processes are spawned as daemons that don't terminate or get terminated after they finish some initial processing; they stay in the background monitoring, processing or responding to certain events. Daemons don't usually transmit 'finished', 'terminated' or any other relevant event message as long as they're still running.

Your second 'approach' is therefore also near impossible, because there's no guarantee that a daemon will do heavy lifting --or any processing at all-- as soon it's fired up. Windows, and almost any other modern operating systems, executes services and start up programs concurrently.

One thing I don't understand is why you wouldn't just start using your computer immediately once the Start button appears. If you feel your computer's start up time is too much, consider optimizing Vista by minimizing start up programs, defragmenting your Windows (system) partition, etc. Finally, if you have less than 2 GB of RAM on your computer, adding another gigabyte will probably give noticeable performance bump.

Comment: Sorry - I was interrupted.

I was kind of expection answers like these. But I had to ask anyway.

I am rebooting because I shut down completely when I go to bed. But this particular case is for a laptop that needs some special care, and I often find, that starting programs on top of Vista is lagging badly until some start-up processes are done.

Comment: ...
Of course a lot of items need to start and keep running, but I was hoping to make some kind of mark anyway. In order to time (as exactly as I could get it) to see what my progress becomes - rather than living in uncertainty. Oh well. Next life or OS

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous boot startup time tools out there.  Vista has its own.  Procmon is another that comes to mind. The question though is, why are you booting up so much?

Sleep/hibernate/resume are far better options than shutting down/ booting up.

**edit:**

This is also hard to define. Vista specifically designed the bootup to where items would startup in a staggered fashion in order to allow the interface to run smoothly. Typically, benchmarks would just hit the start button and when the start menu appears, mark that as the end of bootup.